# Qt QMainWindow Control Dropshadow and its Color

Tags: c++, css, qt

I was just wondering, is there any way at all to control the drop-shadow effect around an active QMainWindow? Here is a picture:

[image]

I would like to be able to control the color of that shadow, and possibly even change the size of it, too. Is there any way to do this? I am adding CSS as a tag because i'm pretty sure this might require using their skinning system.

Comment: I'm going to be putting this up for bounty if no one can answer it. Controlling this shadow needs to happen.

Comment: I think you'll find Windows itself is doing this, as every application gets it. You can turn it on and off with a Windows API call, but you might not be able to set the colour.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HamishMoffatt I am aware that it is Windows controlling it, I was just wondering if there is a way to intercept it with Qt, or via any other outside methods.

Comment: I think such windows decorations are responsibility of the system window manager.
It can be easily achieved in child widgets as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718827/qt-shadow-around-window/23752747#23752747. But I think doing that with top-level windows and in a portable manner will require a tricky solution.

Comment: @mhcuervo I am developing for Windows only. Portability is not an issue.