# Shadow around window in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, dropshadow

I have gone through [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718827/qt-shadow-around-window).

For enhancing my custom shadow around my widget/window.But the Problem is i cant use in PyQt5

**QT_BEGIN_NAMESPAC
Eextern Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT void qt_blurImage(QPainter *p, QImage &blurImage, qreal radius, bool quality, bool alphaOnly, int transposed = 0 );
QT_END_NAMESPACE***

and the Function **qt_blurImage(&blurPainter, tmp, blurRadius(), false, true);** described in that page in **customshadoweffect.cpp**

Can anyone Suggest how to implement that??

Here is my code.
**-EDIT-**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import sip
import ctypes
#This functions is not exposed for PyQt, but can be accessed through ctypes
_qt_blurImage  = getattr(ctypes.CDLL(r"E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin\Qt5Widgets.dll"), 
        '?qt_blurImage@@YAXPAVQPainter@@AAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z')
class CustomShadowEffect(QGraphicsEffect):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._distance=4.0
        self._blurRadius=10.0
        self._color=QColor (0, 0, 0, 80)
    def setBlurRadius(self, blurRadius) :
        self._blurRadius = blurRadius
        self.updateBoundingRect()  
    def blurRadius(self) :
        return self._blurRadius  
    def setColor(self, color):
         self._color = color
    def color(self) :
         return self._color
    def setDistance(self,distance) :
        self._distance = distance
        self. updateBoundingRect()
    def distance(self) :
         return self._distance
    def boundingRectFor( self,rect) :
        delta = self.blurRadius() + self.distance()
        return rect.united(rect.adjusted(-delta, -delta, delta, delta))
       
    def draw(self, painter):

        # if nothing to show outside the item, just draw source
        if ((self.blurRadius() + self.distance()) <= 0) :
            self.drawSource(painter);
            return;
        
        
        mode = QGraphicsEffect.PadToEffectiveBoundingRect #return PixmapPadMode
        # offset=QPoint()
        px,offset = self.sourcePixmap(Qt.DeviceCoordinates, mode)

        # return if no source
        if (px.isNull()):
            return
        
        #save world transform
        restoreTransform = painter.worldTransform() #return QTransform
        painter.setWorldTransform(QTransform())

        #Calculate size for the background image
        szi=QSize (int(px.size().width() + 2 * self.distance()), int(px.size().height() + 2 * self.distance()))

        tmp=QImage(szi, QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        scaled = px.scaled(szi) #return QPixmap
        tmp.fill(0)
        tmpPainter=QPainter(tmp)
        tmpPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Source)
        tmpPainter.drawPixmap(QPointF(-self.distance(), -self.distance()), scaled)
        tmpPainter.end()

        #blur the alpha channel
        blurred=QImage(tmp.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        blurred.fill(0)
        blurPainter=QPainter(blurred)
        self.applyBlurEffect(blurPainter, tmp, self.blurRadius(), False, True)
        blurPainter.end()

        tmp = blurred

        #blacken the image...
        tmpPainter.begin(tmp)
        tmpPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_SourceIn)
        tmpPainter.fillRect(tmp.rect(), self.color())
        tmpPainter.end()

        #draw the blurred shadow...
        painter.drawImage(offset, tmp)

        #draw the actual pixmap...
        painter.drawPixmap(offset, px, QRectF())

        #restore world transform
        painter.setWorldTransform(restoreTransform)
    def applyBlurEffect(self, painter,blurImage, radius, quality, alphaOnly, transposed=0 ):
        blurImage = ctypes.c_void_p(sip.unwrapinstance(blurImage))
        radius = ctypes.c_double(radius)
        quality = ctypes.c_bool(quality)
        alphaOnly = ctypes.c_bool(alphaOnly)
        transposed = ctypes.c_int(transposed)
        if painter:
            painter = ctypes.c_void_p(sip.unwrapinstance(painter))
        _qt_blurImage(painter, blurImage, radius, quality, alphaOnly, transposed)
           

if __name__=="__main__": 
    app=QApplication([])
    win=QWidget()
    win.resize(400,400)
    l=QLabel(win)
    l.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
    l.setStyleSheet("background:green;border-radius:15px;color:white;font: 18pt Calibri;")
    l.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    bodyShadow = CustomShadowEffect(l)
    bodyShadow.setBlurRadius(20.0)
    bodyShadow.setDistance(10.0)
    bodyShadow.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 200))
    l.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    l.setGraphicsEffect(bodyShadow)
    l.setText("hello")
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**Note**
If you want to use shadow for whole window then Use **QWidget** instead

```
if __name__=="__main__": 
    app=QApplication([])
    win=QMainWindow()
    win.resize(400,400)
    l=QWidget(win)
    l.setGeometry(10,10,380,380)
    win.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    win.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    l.setStyleSheet("background:green;border-radius:15px;")
    bodyShadow = CustomShadowEffect(l)
    bodyShadow.setBlurRadius(5.0)
    bodyShadow.setDistance(5.0)
    bodyShadow.setColor(QColor(23, 144, 255, 255))
    l.setGraphicsEffect(bodyShadow)
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: qt_blurImage: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895316/6622587

Comment: Those functions are not exposed for PyQt, but can be accessed through ctypes. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891262/how-to-make-a-beautiful-neon-effect

Comment: Thanks.It workes.But it makes mu widget smaller.i dont know why? and I cant even set text and give border-radius to Qlabel . Its  visible only bottom-right not for around.Can you tell where i did mistake?

Comment: Now it worked. Tahnks @eyllanesc & @musicamante. I have made mistake for which it makes my widget smaller. `offset=QPoint()
    px = self.sourcePixmap(Qt.DeviceCoordinates, mode)[0]
` Now I will edit the post with aWorking Code.